# Get Index if String in ArrayList if contains " "

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read a file to an arraylist. This is solved, and I put one line of the file to a block in the arraylist. However during the process I want to get the index of the block, if the line to be inserted contains a certain somthing. Here what I have done so far. I am stuck.

```
public class practice3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(new FileReader("StudData1.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> ArrayData = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        while (data.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayData.add(i, data.nextLine());
            if (data.nextLine().contains("ID: ")) {
                System.out.print(ArrayData.indexOf(ArrayData.contains("ID: ")));
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        // System.out.print(ArrayData.get(2));
        // System.out.print(ArrayData.size());
    }
}
```

Example :

```
************************
Student N. 1  
ID: 4450
Surname: Wol
Name: Verine
************************

--------------------------------
Subject N. 1 : a. Boat Mantenance
--------------------------------
Homework 1: 89

Homework 2: 56

Homework 3: 65

Homework 4: 3

Exam 1: 35

Exam 2: 45

Exam 3: 89

Exam 4: 99
```

Comment: can you post an example for the text data?

Comment: you are calling nextLine() twice. Remember the value in a string variable and check with this value.

Comment: Also try to avoid starting variable names with uppercase letters. Nothing massive, just some advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pls:

```
    while(data.hasNextLine())
    {
        //if you call nextLine() two times you will get two different items
        String data = data.nextLine();  
        ArrayData.add(i, data);

        if (data.contains("ID: "))
        {
            System.out.print(ArrayData.indexOf(data));  
           //check the index of data, but that should be equal to i. no idea what you want to do here?
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this :

```
String line = data.nextLine();

ArrayData.add(i, line);

if (line.contains("ID: ")) {
    // do what you want here
}
...
```

because when you do `data.nextLine()` it reads the current line and pass to the next one

Comment: @kai you're right, I haven't pay attention to that block of code. But even know I don't know what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check your while loop. every time you are calling `data.nextLine()` it advance to next line. You are calling it twice. first while adding to arraylist and second while checking condition. you are actually adding half of the file and checking for condition on every alternative line.